# I see vs. I can see [the usage of the instantaneous Present Simple)

Tags: tenses, present-tense

From Fly High 4 by Jeanne Perrette & Charlotte Covill (suspiciously French-sounding names...) by Pearson Longman, unit 13, page 40, "They went through town":

"I **can see** Claudia and Magnus," shouted Jack. They're getting on the train. Run!"

Isn't the instantaneous Present Simple more appropriate in the given context and doesn't it describe the events more accurately?

"I **see** Claudia and Magnus," shouted Jack. They're getting on the train. Run!" ?

Answer (score 1):

Both *I can see Claudia and Magnus* and *I see Claudia and Magnus* are possible. Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p102) notes that the first variation is more common in British English, while the second is more common in American English:

> **Section 125 see, hear, feel smell, taste**
>
> ...To talk about  seeing, hearing etc at a particular moment, we often
>   use *can see, can hear* etc (especially in British English):
>
> - I can see Susan coming.
> - ...I can taste something funny.
>
> In American English, *I see/hear* etc are common in this sense.